# C Programming: strtol() and Dealing with NUL Bytes

Tags: c, char, hex

Say I have an address and an offset like:

```
   char* base_addr = "\x00\x00\x00\xb7";
   char* addr_offset = (user input);
```

and I want to add base_addr and addr_offset together. Would I have to write my own strtol() function that doesn't terminate at a NUL or is there another way I can successfully add the two addresses?

EDIT:

Forgot to say that this is Linux x86.

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you mean about adding user input to an existing string. But, basically, yeah write your own function. This should be trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`base_addr` is actually a 32-bit integer value, that just happens to have been hard-coded using byte constants.  You should simply cast the type of the pointer to `unsigned long`, then call `strtol()` on the string entered by the user, and sum the two.

It's lame to hard-code a pointer using a string that way.  For one thing, C will add a NUL byte to the end of the string, so now your 32-bit value takes 5 bytes, and with padding bytes added you might end up using 8 bytes to store your pointer, exactly double what is needed.  Better to do it this way:

```
char base_addr[] = {'\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\xb7'};
```

Even better to just say what you mean, as long as the compiler will let you do the type cast:

```
unsigned char *base_addr = (unsigned char *)0xb7000000;
```

I just checked, and GCC lets you do the above without error or warning.

EDIT: Oh, okay, the real question is how to get access to the bytes inside an integer value.

You should be able to do this just by messing with pointers:

```
unsigned long base_adr = 0xb700000000;
unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)&base_adr;
```

The above trick works with integer types.  The other way to do it is with a C union:

```
typedef union
{
    char bytes[4];
    unsigned long n;
    unsigned char *ptr;
} ADR_WINDOW;

ADR_WINDOW x;

x.n = 0xb700000000;
assert(x.bytes[3] == 0xb7); // on a little-endian computer
assert(x.bytes[0] == 0xb7); // on a big-endian computer
```

The union trick works for any type, and is the only portable way to do sleazy tricks like looking at the bits inside a float value.

Comment: How can I get the unsigned long back into a string after I've added the two together (I need it as a string containing little endian bytes)?

Comment: I don't think that's correct. You can cast anything to `char*`. Why should it be different for ints and floats? Using unions like that is technically undefined behavior. You should prefer `uintptr_t`/`uint32_t` instead of `unsigned long`.

Comment: Good point about `uintptr_t`.  But in my experience, trying to access the bits inside a float is a fast way to get GCC to complain about "type-punned pointers".  I'm not sure you are correct about the union trick being undefined behavior; that is the closest thing C has to an official way to do this, and I have found it to be completely portable, even to DSP chips.  The ordering of bytes inside an integer value is dependent on the endianness of the system, of course.